# Istance fragment issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

It's not my aim to spam.
I built an app, everything works fine except the fragment istance.
In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AmAiUwC5eeE) at 0:13 seconds you can watch better the issue: basically when a new Fragment is created an annoying red bar appears for some fraction of seconds (while loading the page) and I don't like it.
The bottomBar code is the following:

```
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener nagListener   = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( @NonNull MenuItem item )
    {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch ( item.getItemId() )
        {
            case R.id.navigation_journal:
                selectedFragment    =   myclass1.newInstance();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_statistics:
                selectedFragment    =   myclass2.newInstance();
                break;
        }

        if ( selectedFragment != null )
        {
            Fragment oldFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_layout);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.remove( oldFragment );
            transaction.add( R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment );
            transaction.commit();

            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Meanwhile in each `myclass*` I have the following function:

```
public static myclass1 newInstance()
{
    myclass1 fragment = new myclass1();
    return fragment;
}
```

All my fragment layouts are `CoordinatorLayout` which looks like to be the only one working (I tried to change it without success). Changing the theme of the layout doesn'help.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="mypackage.myclass1"
    android:background="@color/background_activities"
    >
```

Comment: why show a video ?? which doesnt demonstrate an issue ??

Comment: Because it was too fast for taking a screenshot, and I have this issue from the beginning - now the app is released and all the maior issues are solved, I am focusing on minors

Comment: Cool , but you could take the record of *just* the part which demonstrates the issue...so that the viewer can focus on it, frankly speaking  *from that video* i dint get what the actual issue is !!

Comment: That's why I wrote the time: 0:13, when I change the Fragment from the NavigationBar, one second later - you can see the red bar just below the Toolbox bar which disappears when the fragment is completely created.

Comment: i got it now, try `replacing` instead of adding and check if it works !!

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately...